# What does fine-tuning a multilingual checkpoint mean?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, fine-tuning

I'm fine-tuning a SetFit model on a French dataset and following the guide in [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/blog/setfit). They mention this point on the site that I didn't quite understand

> " Multilingual support: SetFit can be used with any Sentence
> Transformer on the Hub, which means you can classify text in multiple
> languages by simply fine-tuning a multilingual checkpoint."

Does that mean I must find an already finetuned SetFit model in French when loading the model? As in replace "paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2" below with a French one?

```
model = SetFitModel.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the point in the guide suggests is that multilingual models fine-tuned using `SetFit` method generalize well even on languages they did not see during the `SetFit` fine-tuning process. This seems to be generally true for multilingual language models but it probably does not do any damage to mention it explicitly, particularly when discussing `SetFit`, which is a method which usually works with a very small dataset (i.e. the dataset that might not be multilingual).

The finding is supported by the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.11055.pdf) mentioned in the guide, where researchers show that model fine-tuned on English data using `SetFit` performs well on variety of languages (see table 4).

What I would take from it is this: if you fine-tune multilingual checkpoint (e.g. [`sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2`](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2)) and fine-tune it on French, it will perform well on French and probably will also perform well on other languages. If you plan to use the fine-tuned model only on French texts, you certainly can and try to fine-tune a specifically French model - however, it's certainly not true that you *must* do this.

However, if there exists a specifically French sentence transformer and you want to use your model only on French texts, I would recommend using the French model. Not because you must, but because it might perform better than the multilingual model.